# Unity C# coroutine not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a Simon game. Obviously, when one color is displayed, it should wait a second or so. I created a coruotine for when the game is showing you what to do. Inside the coroutine, it is supposed to pause first, which when I run the game, it does. Then it goes through and chooses a color and stuff. Then it should loop back up(I made a loop) and pause again, and do everything again. The problem is, the pause only works the first time. Then it displays the other colors for like half a second and ends. I don't understand why once it loops it seems to do everything except for the pause. Here is my code:

```
void Update () {
    if (show == true) {
        StartCoroutine(Show());
    }
}

IEnumerator Show() {
    do {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
        round ++;

        if (round == 1) {
            on = Random.Range(1,5);
        }

        if (round == 2) {
            on = Random.Range(1,5);
        }

        if (round == 3) {
            on = Random.Range(1,5);
        }

        if (round == 4) {
            on = Random.Range(1,5);
        }

        // Turn on/off lights
        if (on == 1) {
            green.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = greenMat;
        }
        if (on != 1) {
            green.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = greenOff;
        }
        if (on == 2) {
            red.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = redMat;
        }
        if (on != 2) {
            red.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = redOff;
        }
        if (on == 3) {
            yellow.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = yellowMat;
        }
        if (on != 3) {
            yellow.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = yellowOff;
        }
        if (on == 4) {
            blue.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = blueMat;
        }
        if (on != 4) {
            blue.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = blueOff;
        }
    }while(show == true);
}
```

Comment: It is hard to understand your question and your problem. I suggest you rephrase your question and say what you are trying to do then tell us what is happening now. Also, not accepting useful answers in your other questions will discourage people from helping you.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a coroutine which may help you. Put it on start.

```
    IEnumerator Show()
{
    while (true) // or show 
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);

        round ++;
        if (round >= 1 && round <= 4) 
            on = Random.Range(1,5);

        green.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = on == 1 ? greenMat : greenOff;

        //Same for the other...
    }
}
```